# Archive & unarchive directories in Perl on Windows 2003

Tags: windows, perl

There are two drives on Windows server A: ( mapped filesystem) G:(Local drive)

I want to take a back of a directory ( & subdirectories in it) say "backup" from G drive to A: drive using perl and archiving and then unarchiving and without disturbing the folder structure in the Backup folder.

Comment: I re-read the question three times but I still don't understand exactly what you are trying to achieve/on what point you need help.

Comment: Back up of a directory and its subdirectories from a Local drive to a mapped filesystem, without disturbing the internal directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

I can lay out the basic idea with [`File::Find`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aFind) and [`Archive::Zip`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Archive%3a%3aZip):

```
use Archive::Zip qw( :ERROR_CODES :CONSTANTS );
use File::Find qw<find>;

my $zip = Archive::Zip->new();
find sub { $zip->addFile( $File::Find::name ); } => $my_directory;
$zip->writeToFileNamed( $my_zip_file_name );
```

Extraction can be as simple as:

```
$zip->extractTree( $root_in_zipfile, $external_destination )
```

[See](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Archive%3a%3aZip#%24zip-%3EextractTree%28_%24root,_%24dest_%29)

Comment: Back up of a directory and its subdirectories from a Local drive to a mapped filesystem, without disturbing the internal directory structure.I tried a shell command as well which worked on unix platform but is not working on Windows 2003.Command is as below : tar cpf - nt_sp |(cd ${SNAPSHOT_HOME}/${RELNUM}/Baseline; tar xpf -)